# How to use ajax to connect to all_book and print out database information on the web page

Tags: java, ajax, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect to databases and export information to webpages, but writing Ajax always triggers errors instead of success

This is an exercise I did to learn microservices.

```
    public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book,Integer> {
    }
```

```
    @Entity
    public class Book
    {
        public Book() {

        }
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;

        private String book_name;

        private String book_author;

        private String book_pub;

        private String book_num;
```

```
    HelloServiceImpl.class
    @Autowired
        private BookRepository bookRepository;

        @GetMapping("/all_book")
        public List<Book> getbooklist()
        {
            return bookRepository.findAll();
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHaK7.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNH3D.png)

Comment: what are the errors?

Comment: In my insertion, there are two methods for successful acquisition and failed acquisition. After clicking, only error method is triggered.

Comment: Unless you make a minimal proof-of-concept for your issue, I don't think someone can help you.